# How to stop extra authentication with admin area

Tags: admin, authentication

When I am logged in as any user on my EE site (including superadmins), when I click over to the admin area it forces me to login again. This happens even if I've just logged in 5 seconds earlier. Is there any way to prevent this extra authentication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. It's there as a security feature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I couldn't find a definitive answer one way or the other.